# Python. char как в С/С++

Tags: c++, python, c, char

в с++ машина видит char как целочисленный тип
и можно просто брать и делать так:

```
string str ..что то..
char t = str[i] - 'a'
```

И тому подобное 
Но, как сделать подобное в python? Ведь при приведении строки к инту, оно выдаст ошибку если это не число. А типа сhar в python нет насколько я знаю.

Comment: Можно использовать `s = 'что-то'; ord(s[i])`

Comment: *в с++ машина видит char как целочисленный тип*  -- можно подробней рассказать про этот поток сознания?

Comment: @PinkTux к примеру по первой ссылке в гугле "c++ char"
Символьная переменная — это числовая переменная, которая используется для представления символов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `ord` даёт численное значение символа, если нужна какая-то арифметика

```
>> chr(ord('x') + 1)
'y'
```

> function ord() would get the int value of the char. And in case you
>   want to convert back after playing with the number, function chr()
>   does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

`char` тип представляет байт в Си. В Питоне, набор байт может быть представлен `bytes` типом. В Питоне 3:

```
>>> b'abc'
b'abc'
>>> b'abc'[0]
97
```

то есть байт уже возвращается как число (`int`) и его не нужно преобразовывать.